# Slick.js not working with Polymer 2.0

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, polymer, slick.js

I try to make my own component with Slick.js library but it seems not working with Polymer 2.0

I have no error in the debug console and nothing appear on the browser

Here's the code :

```
<template>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendors/slick-1.6.0/slick/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendors/slick-1.6.0/slick/slick-theme.css">

    <div id="sliderNews">
        <div><img src="../images/background_baseline.jpeg"></div>
        <div><img src="../images/background_baseline.jpeg"></div>
        <div><img src="../images/background_baseline.jpeg"></div>
        <div><img src="../images/background_baseline.jpeg"></div>
        <div><img src="../images/background_baseline.jpeg"></div>
    </div>

</template>
<script>

    class WorkadvisorModuleNews extends Polymer.Element {

        static get is() { return 'workadvisor-module-news'; }

        static get properties() { return {

            placeholderImg: {
                type: String,
                observer: '_placeholderImgChanged'
            }

        }}

        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        ready() {
            super.ready();
        }

        connectedCallback() {
            super.connectedCallback();
            $(this.$.sliderNews).slick({
                infinite: true,
                arrows: true,
                dots: true,
                slidesToShow: 1
            });
        }
    }

    customElements.define(WorkadvisorModuleNews.is, WorkadvisorModuleNews);

</script>
<script src="../vendors/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/slick-1.6.0/slick/slick.js"></script>
```

I've tried to move .js files imported to the index.html but nothing more.
Same for .css files.

Comment: [UPDATE] : I moved css files BEFORE <template> tag and the <dom-module> tag and result -> Previous/Next Button appears and six buttons with their dots but no errors occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using external stylesheets has been [deprecated](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#external-stylesheets) in Polymer 2. The alternative and preferred way to share styles is with style modules.If you want to learn more about style modules [click here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#style-modules).

Basically, to create a style module, you need to wrap your style block in `<dom-module>` and `<template>` elements, like this:

```
<dom-module id="my-style">
  <template>
    <style>
      <!-- Styles to share go here! -->
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

When you create the element that will use the styles, import the style module and include in the opening tag of the style block:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-style.html">
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style include="my-style">
      <!-- Any additional styles go here -->
    </style>
    <!-- The rest of your element template goes here -->
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Demo using slick.js library: http://plnkr.co/edit/PP1uIUICNP4uFZAjZfZb?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, but i created slick-css.html like your demo (not styles-css as i said) and import slick-css.html and include slick-css but always no images appear...

Comment: Problem solved! Its due to another thing in my component, Images were behind the background-image so i cant see them.